# How prove that the 2-form of the hamiltonian formalism is a sympletic form?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

The form What I say is

$$\omega=  dp_{\mu}\land dq^{\mu} $$
(I wrote anyway because the question is quick) how prove that are sympletic, i prove  that $$d\omega=0$$but how prove that this is non-degenerate?

Obs:For those who have not read the title q is position and p is momentum

In my attempts I used another vector field that I found out now was the reason I wasn't able to prove it, but would it be that I could prove it  with this vector field?

$$X(f) =\partial_{p{\mu}}f \partial_{q^{\mu}} - \partial _{q^{\mu}}f  \partial_{p{\mu}}$$

To better understand the notation

If $$f(q, p) =H(q, p) (hamiltonian) $$

$$X(H) =\frac{d} {dt} $$

Comment: you need to typeset this properly: right now it’s near impossible to get a clear idea of what you are asking.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: Okay I'll write here and edit

Comment: Ready look at it and see if you know this form

Comment: much better indeed.

Comment: Are you missing subindices if your $X(f)$?

Comment: Is a einstein notation sum, is said to be a vector field in a direction, for a hamiltonian is d/dt, the notation maybe confused But that's it

Comment: Its like a lie derivative

Comment: should be $p_\mu$ not $p\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your trouble may be related to the somewhat artificial splitting between $q$'s and $p$'s here.  Let's take a $2$-dimensional configuration space with coordinates $(q^1,q^2)$.  An arbitrary point in the cotangent bundle then has the four coordinates $x \equiv (q^1,q^2,p_1,p_2)$, so $x^1=q^1,x^2=q^2,x^3=p_1,x^4=p_2$.

In this language, the canonical $2$-form can be written
$$\omega= \mathrm dx^3\wedge \mathrm dx^1 + \mathrm dx^4 \wedge \mathrm dx^2  $$
$$\equiv \frac{1}{2}\big(\mathrm dx^3\otimes \mathrm dx^1 - \mathrm dx^1 \otimes \mathrm dx^3 + \mathrm dx^4 \otimes \mathrm dx^2 - \mathrm dx^2 \otimes \mathrm dx^4\big)$$
If we feed this $2$-form two arbitrary vectors $A = \sum_{n=1}^4 A^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}$ and $B = \sum_{n=1}^4 B^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}$, we obtain
$$\omega(A,B)= \frac{1}{2}\big(A^3B^1-A^1B^3 + A^4B^2 - A^2 B^4\big)$$
Recall that $\omega$ is non-degenerate $\iff \omega(A,B)=0$ for all $B$ **implies** that $A=0$.  If the expression $\omega(A,B)$ written above is equal to zero for every possible vector $B$, what does that tell you about $A$?

---

> In my attempts I used another vector field that I found out now was the reason I wasn't able to prove it, but would it be that I could prove it  with this vector field?
> $$X(f) =\partial_{p{\mu}}f \partial_{q^{\mu}} - \partial _{q^{\mu}}f  \partial_{p{\mu}}$$
> To better understand the notation
> If $$f(q, p) =H(q, p) (hamiltonian) $$
> $$X(H) =\frac{d} {dt} $$

I believe I understand your follow-up question. Let the phase space be given by $X$. Given a non-degenerate $(0,2)$-tensor $B:TX\times TX\rightarrow \mathbb R$, one can define a map $\flat: TX \rightarrow T^*X$ via $ A^\flat := B(A,\cdot)$, where $\cdot$ denotes an empty slot.  In component form,
$$(A^\flat)_\mu = B_{\mu\nu} A^\nu$$
If we define $\tilde B$ to be the $(2,0)$-tensor whose components are the matrix inverse of the components of $B$ (by which I mean, $\tilde B^{\mu\alpha} B_{\alpha\nu} = \delta^\mu_\nu$) then $\tilde B$ defines the inverse map
$$\sharp : T^*X \rightarrow TX$$
$$(\alpha^\sharp)^\mu = \tilde B^{\mu\nu} \alpha_\nu$$

This association between the tangent vectors and covectors is called a [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism), and it is well-defined if and only if $B$ is non-degenerate (so that the matrix $B_{\mu\nu}$ is invertible).

---

With that out of the way, to each smooth function $f$ corresponds a so-called *Hamiltonian vector field* $X_f$ given by $X_f := (\mathrm df)^\sharp$, where the musical isomorphism is provided by $\omega$.  In canonical coordinates, one has that

$$f \mapsto X_f = \sum_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_n} \frac{\partial}{\partial q^n} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^n} \frac{\partial}{\partial p_n}$$

The association $\mathrm df \leftrightarrow X_f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\omega$ is non-degenerate.  In explicit component form (in canonical coordinates), the association takes the form

$$\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^2},\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial p_2}\right)}_{\text{components of }\mathrm df}\leftrightarrow \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_2},-\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^1}, -\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^2}\right)}_{\text{components of }X_f}$$

It's obvious that this is an isomorphism - the components are just shuffled around, modulo a minus sign - and so the bilinear form $\omega$ from which it is derived must be non-degenerate.

Comment: Makes sense thank you, My difficulty is that I received another vector field I will add the question to show you, But yes that answers my question, I was a little incompetent in thinking that the field you showed was going to be harder which really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I put there could tell if you could prove it with that

Comment: The notation may seem confusing but I think you're going to understand the expression

Comment: @Ian I've edited my answer to address your follow-up.

Comment: Our thanks, damn very good

Comment: I've confirmed your response